# How to have a prevent react from looking up for dependency of react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dependencies, npm-install, npm-package

I have a common package named `A` which is accessed by both react and react-native but due to some functionality I have to download a package that is specifically for react-native now its giving me error when I compile my react code.

So a certain solution that will work is to find a package that works for both but i wanted to ask is there a way to prevent react from compiling that package or something like that?

Thank you

Comment: The only way is to use another package sadly...